# Will Apache Flink restore trigger timers after failure?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Some custom trigers has a state and using timers (i.e. in [this example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/windowing/SessionWindowing.java#L103)).

As I understand the state [will be restored](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state.html#working-with-state) after failure but how about timers? Will they be restored after failure automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes timers will be checkpointed and restored upon a failure case.

However, there is a subtle detail to understand here. Whenever you register a processing timer, the `WindowOperator` will save the future timestamp in a queue and schedule a timer task which will trigger the `WindowOperator`. If a `WindowOperator` is triggered it will process all registered timer events whose timestamps are lower than the current timestamp.

Flink will only checkpoint the queue of future timestamp but not the scheduled timer tasks. That implies that in a recovery case you will have restored the queue of future timestamps but no timer task to trigger the `WindowOperator` (which then triggers the timer events). So you need to wait for a new element which will register a new timer task. Once this timer task fires, all the other timer events with a lower timestamp will be executed.

This subtleness does not apply to event time processing since you don't have a timer task which triggers the `WindowOperator` but watermarks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the behavior changed in recent releases.
Now "the current behavior is that all timers (both processing time and event time) are re-registered on restore, and therefore should be triggered automatically".

This is a reference to the relevant message  in the flink list: 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201804.mbox/%3CF0F57EB6-54E9-4303-AD95-EBB367B899E4@apache.org%3E